# Using neither alone in a sentence

Tags: grammar, neither-nor

I have trouble with the use of "neither" in some sentences. Example:

1. “You must not drink sodas, neither eat fast food.”
2. “You must not drink sodas neither eat fast food.”

(I don't know if I have to include a comma)

The thing is that I want to use “neither” alone in this kind of cases, but some apps, like Grammarly, change it to “**or**” like:

> “You must not drink sodas or eat fast food.”

I don't understand why this is correct. Now I see that using neither here is incorrect, but I don't really get why.

Comment: hmmm, I'd put 'nor' instead of 'or'.  Very technically, when using 'or' you could eat fast food AND drink sodas.

Comment: "Neither" is the opposite of "either." Would you write, "You can drink sodas either eat fast food"?

Comment: @mcalex so using “nor” in this sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: @DavidK, No, I wouldn't write it , now I get why neither is no correct here.

Comment: @Mary yes.  If you replace 'not' with 'neither', it will make 'nor' more obviously correct. - "You must neither drink sodas nor eat fast food." as Old Brixtonian says in their answer (and is probably the variant I'd use).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word **neither** is used in a few different ways.  Usually it's used before nouns like a determiner, for example

"You must eat or drink **neither** fast food nor soda."

Note that *not* doesn't appear here - *neither* is like a way of negating the noun (*neither fast food nor soda*) and not the verb (*you must not*...)

You're trying to use it like a conjunction or maybe an adverb, in which case the correct phrasing would be

"You must not eat fast food, **neither** must you drink soda."

References:

- [Neither, neither … nor and not … either](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2)
- [HOW TO USE EITHER, NEITHER, NOR AND OR](https://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/learning-languages/eng/how-to-use-either-neither-nor-and-or)

Comment: For clarity, are you saying OP has to switch the two items, or will your solution (inserting 'must you') work with the sodas first and food second?

Comment: I would personally put "neither" before the verbs (with appropriate corresponding changes), or use "consume" instead of "eat or drink". "A or B neither C nor D" sounds a bit strange.

Comment: "nor" seems more idiomatic to me than "neither" in your last example, although I believe both are acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

You could say, with *at least* a comma in the middle,

> You must not drink sodas. Neither must you eat fast food.

Or, in one unbroken but slightly old-fashioned sentence:

> "You must neither drink sodas nor eat fast food.”

I don't know why you want to use "neither". Most people would probably do as Grammarly suggested, but with "mustn't" instead of "must not", as NotThatGuy suggests.

Comment: I don't know why you call "neither X nor Y" "old-fashioned". I hear that structure quite often. I certainly hear that far more often than "... not X. Neither Y". If anything, I'd consider the latter to be "old-fashioned" and quite formal. But in common speech many people will probably just say "You mustn't drink sodas nor eat fast food" (regardless of whether or not this is strictly grammatical).

Comment: I too hear "**It's** neither X nor Y." But "**You** must neither X nor Y" sounds pleasantly dated to me! I've seldom heard "You mustn't X **nor**..." Grammarly's "You  mustn't X **or**..." - with your "mustn't" - is probably the most used in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why [the use of "or"] is correct.

It's correct (and natural to me, as a native BrE speaker) to use "or" here because you're indicating alternatives.  There are two actions mentioned, and someone could do either of them; you're indicating that it would be wrong to do either of the alternatives.

If you were to use **and** here by contrast, it would indicate a single compound action:

> "You must not drink sodas and eat fast food"

This says you must not do **both**, at the same time - but it's presumably OK to drink sodas so long as you're not also eating fast food, or vice versa.

Using **or** instead makes it clear that each individual part is forbidden; if you do one of them *or* the other one, you've broken the rule.

Comment: Without additional punctuation "You must not drink sodas and eat fast food" is ambiguous. Is it to mean "You must, not drink sodas, and eat fast food" or "You must not, drink sodas and east fast food" ? You are quite right that the use of 'or' resolves the problem.